# Django - Query for Posts belonging to Goals by Categories?

Tags: python, django

So I have some models where each Category is comprised of Goals. For example, "Health" is a category and "lose 10lbs by my wedding" is a goal in that category. Then I have posts for that goal. So like post 1 could be about day 1 of the weight loss journey and so on and so forth. I need to be able to query for all posts by category and the response should be a list of dict where it contains: the post body, goal title, create date. How can I query for this quickly? The current method I have I think is less than ideal. I was going to query goals by category than query posts by goal, but then I'd had to iteratively append the goal description to every post then return it. This could be very slow. I think ideally I'd want to filter categories by the category I want then join on goals with that type then join on posts and return the relevant columns.

```
class Goal(AbstractBaseModel):
    creator_id = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="goal_creator_id")
    end_date = models.DateField(
        'End date', null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(GoalCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)])

class Post(AbstractBaseModel):
    creator_id = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator_id")
    goal_id = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=511, validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)])
    hash_tags = models.ManyToManyField(HashTag)

class GoalCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True, validators=[
                                MinLengthValidator(5)])
    emoji_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083, validators=[
                                 MinLengthValidator(8)])


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_most_recent_posts_by_category(request, category, count):
    goal_uuid_list = list(Goal.objects.filter(category = category).values_list('uuid', flat=True))
    Post.objects.filter(goal_id__in=goal_uuid_list).values('description', 'uuid')
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution, but it seems less than ideal, because I also have to rename keys

```
def get_most_recent_posts_by_category(request, category, count):
    goals_list = list(Goal.objects.filter(category = category).values_list('uuid', flat=True))
    data = list(Post.objects.filter(goal_id__in=goals_list).order_by('created').values('body', 'goal_id__description', 'created'))
    data['goal_description'] = data['goal_id__description']
    data['post_body'] = data['body']
    del data['goal_description']
    del data['body']
    return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```